# css - Insert image on top of each li text

Tags: html, css, image, list

What would be the best way to insert a small image on-top  of each list element? like this :

[image]

Thanks for any help!

---

i tried this but its not look like the image !

```css
.top-menu-ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
}

.top-menu-ul li {
    float: right;
    margin: 50px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top-menu-ul">
  <li><img align="center" src="imgz/icon.png" alt=""><a href="">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><img align="center" src="imgz/icon.png" alt=""><a href="">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><img align="center" src="imgz/icon.png" alt=""><a href="">TEXT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the best way is coding.

Comment: What is the problem with making each element a div container that has two elements (can be sub divs) with each containing an img and a text element respectively? Have you tried anything yet? If so please share your code so we can have an idea and help better.

Answer (score -1):

A simple `<br/>` between the elements, and some centering should do it:

```css
.top-menu-ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

.top-menu-ul li {
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align:center;
}

.top-menu-ul > :first-child
{
  border-left:solid 1px #dddddd;
}

.top-menu-ul li img {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top-menu-ul">
  <li><img align="center" src="imgz/icon.png" alt=""><br/><a href="">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><img align="center" src="imgz/icon.png" alt=""><br/><a href="">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><img align="center" src="imgz/icon.png" alt=""><br/><a href="">TEXT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is really not the [proper way to use `<br>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element) and we shouldn't tell people to use it like that